# Interpolation of data from table

Tags: interpolation

How to do the interpolation of this data, so that I can plot the interpolated functionafter interpolation

```
 dat1 = Import["newdel(0.5).txt", "Table"]
```

The entries of the data table are ,x ,y ,z .But Z is fixed to some number say 1000, and x varies from 0.01 to 0.5 and y from 1000 to 5000. X Y and Z table has been generated after solving an inequality.

This is the Listplot from first two entries of the data

[image]

I want tha to remove the discontinuity of data points of this plot in lower part by means of interpolation then i tried the below code , but with errors

---

```
 data1 = Interpolation[dat1]
```

But Got this error  Interpolation on unstructured grids is currently only supported for InterpolationOrder->1 or InterpolationOrder->All. The order will be reduced to 1.

Comment: Post `newdel(0.5).txt` on [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) and put the link in your question.

Comment: It seems to me that you have the fewest points in the region of most interest. That would probably make interpolation not so useful. You probably want a fit to your data, but that requires an appropriate model function. Have you plotted the resulting interpolating function? Was it acceptable? I also second @J.M 's suggestion: without data, we can't help.

Comment: How can i put such a huge data here

Comment: Available  at this link https://pastebin.com/DLMR3SAQ

Comment: @ImmySalam Thank you for including the data. In principle, what equation would this data obey? What could be a good model for it?

Comment: One can get the data set of the first two entries from data and can find the best fit. Am I right?.